# Unable to Drag and Drop for web driver in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code i tried

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement src = driver.findElement(By.id("drag1"));
    WebElement des = driver.findElement(By.id("div2"));

    builder.clickAndHold(src).build().perform();                
    builder.moveToElement(des).build().perform();
    builder.release(des).build().perform();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I don't see the drag and drop operation happening, Although no error is returned in the console.

Am I missing any step here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try with following:

```
builder.dragAndDrop(src, des).build().perform();
```

If above doesn't help you, see if following helps:

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This didn't work. Can you recheck it

Comment: Didn't it throw an error? If not, can you please share the website where I can try and let you know answer if I can?

Comment: No Error please find website in question itself..posted above

Comment: I tried with different possible api's but it's not working. Please see if the link mentioned in the updated answer helps you.

Comment: yea thanks i follow elemental selenium too. Thanks for your inputs.